# Filtering out all non-alphanumeric characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to filter out Unicode characters that aren't related to language from a string.

Here's an example of what I want:

```js
const filt1 = "This will not be replaced: æ Ç ü"; // This will not be replaced: æ Ç ü
const filt2 = "This will be replaced: » ↕ ◄"; // This will be replaced:
```

How would I go about doing this? Characters such as accented letters and Chinese characters are what I want to keep. Arrows, blocks, emoji, etc. should be filtered out.

I've found various regex filters online, but none do exactly what I want.
This one works the best, but it's bulky and does not include non-accented alphanumeric characters.

```js
((?![a-zA-ZàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ ]).)*
```

Comment: I don't think there's any algorithm that determines what you do and don't want to keep so the only way will be brute force to list what you want to keep in a giant string/array.  You can examine code pages from dozens of languages and see if you can find any algorithm based on the character code, but unless you limit yourself to only a few languages, I doubt you're going to find an algorithmic shortcut.

Comment: That was my original idea, but it looks so bulky. Easily doable as seen above, but doesn't feel efficient.

Comment: Did you examine all the code pages you care about and see if the characters you want to keep follow some pattern with their character code?  That's the only possibility I see.  But, if you're going into things like Chinese and not just romance languages, that's unlikely to work.

Comment: @jfriend00 Even just including Cyrillic starts to make it a major pain, adding Chinese, Korean, Japanese, etc is going to be unmaintainable.

Comment: @VLAZ - Yep, that's what I thought.  I think I'd go back to what the real problem is and look for a different approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript + Unicode regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try an unicode regex `/[^\p{L}\s]/ugi`

```js
console.log('This will be replaced: » ↕ ◄, This will not be replaced: æ Ç ü'.replace(/[^\p{L}\s]/ugi, ''));
```

[Unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) have been added in ES2018, the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_property_escapes) is currently limited, node.js [supports them](https://node.green/#ES2018-features--RegExp-Unicode-Property-Escapes) from the version 10.

Comment: can you explain a bit more what the regex does or maybe a link where to read more

Comment: @Edude42: I'd recommend reading the MDN page linked from the answer, but it seems to still be a work in progress. The Wikipedia page on [Unicode character properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property) might be a useful supplement for some of the missing info there.